# How can I show loading percentage along with progress bar in silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am using progress bar in my silverlght 4 project first time.

I have to show progress percentage with the control.

Suppose if there are two xaml pages, first page should show progress bar with percentage of

loading when redirecting to Second page. Here my  second page takes 2 to 3 mins to load.

Can any one help me out?

Thanks & Regards,
NJ

Comment: two quick questions: why is your second page taking so long? and how are you loading it?